# how to use varnish-cache behind a proxy

Tags: caching, proxy, varnish

I would like to use Varnish-cache to cache some of the dependancies of my web application, but I am stuck behind a corporate Proxy setup. Is there any way to tell Varnish-cache to make it's http requests to other services through a proxy?

Many thanks

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you can speak HTTP with the proxy, you can do whatever you want.

Example set-up:

```
[back-end A]          [back-end B]
     |                     |
     ---[corporate proxy]---
                |
            [Varnish]
```

Change the default port from 80 to the proxies port (e.g. 8080) ...

```
backend corp_proxy {
  .host = "proxy.localnet";
  .port = "8080";
}
...
sub vcl_recv {
    ...
    /* check if back-end A or B and use proxy as backend */
    if (req.http.host == "backend-a.example.com" || req.http.host == "backend-b.example.com") {
        set req.backend = corp_proxy;
        set req.http.X-Proxy-Pass = 'mypass';
    }
    ...
}
```

You can even set custom headers in the request (e.g. some static key or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

For varnish4 this does not work. Doing a bit of network tracing, it would appear that varnish v4 does relative req.url, where a proxy needs a absolute req.url
I'm in a split-brain DNS world, so my backend is the same domain-name as the frontend user see (just resovles differently). Therefore i create a absolute URL by using req.http.host in the req.url variable.

```
sub vcl_recv {
    # Setting backend hint
    set req.backend_hint = varnish_backend;
    if (req.url !~ "mydomain.com") {
      set req.url ="http://" + req.http.host + req.url;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly when the varnish backend is a proxy. Thanks.